# Using Ajax to submit form Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a form that is using AJax to submit the form instead of doing a page reload, but every code i've tried does not send anything to the email  i specified.

Here is my code:

compform.php

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $to = "support@quadflowapp.com";// this is your Email address
 $from = $_POST['mail']; // this is the sender's Email address
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $mail = $_POST['mail'];

 $subject = "Quadflow Content Writing Service Request";

 $message = 'Hi Uriel, you have a new content writing request email from Quadflow App';
 $message .= $name;

 $headers = "From:" . $from;

 mail($to,$subject, $message,$headers);

 header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "?mail=sent");
 exit();

}
?>
```

Jquery (Ajax):

```
 $('.compform').submit(function(event) {
    var formData = {
        'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'mail'             : $('input[name=mail]').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'compform.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                    encode          : true
    })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
        });
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.compform button').html('Success!');
});
```

Html

```
<form class="compform" action="compform.php" method="post">  
   <input placeholder="Name" name="name"> 
   <input placeholder="Email" name="mail">
   <input placeholder="Type of Website" name="type"> 
   <select name="selectoptions">
    <option value="choose" disabled selected>Choose a Style</option> 
    <option value="modern">Modern</option>
    <option value="serious">Serious</option>
    <option value="light">Light Tone</option> 
    <option value="creative">Creative</option>
   </select>
   <textarea placeholder="Additional Information" name="info"></textarea>
   <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: try .compform is not a class it's not valid selector because you have not declared it 
Use <form class="compform" action="compform.php" method="post">  
and use 
    event.preventDefault(); 
ON first line of the function code

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit that! I had that in my original coe. But thanks for pointing it out though. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes please update the latest code by editing so that we can give it a try :)

Comment: ok just updated

Comment: you are not using SMTP server right ? if you are testing it on localhost you must provide SMTP credentials for sending email

Comment: i am using my web hosting server for SMTP. When i remove the ajax function and send submit the form the regular way (with page reload) it successfully submits the email to the specified email. It works. But with this ajax code nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first point, you check in your PHP script if the field "submit" is set, but do not pass it in your ajax call. Next you don't give a json response as a answer because you made a forwarding.

Further you are using the `encode` property in your ajax call, [that not seem to exist](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Additionally you can use the `complete` method to get status messages of your ajax call.

All in one you can try this codes (if your `mail` function will work on the regular way)

**PHP**

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $to = "support@quadflowapp.com"; // this is your Email address
  $from = $_POST['mail']; // this is the sender's Email address
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $mail = $_POST['mail'];
  $subject = "Quadflow Content Writing Service Request";

  $message = 'Hi Uriel, you have a new content writing request email from Quadflow App';
  $message .= $name;

  $headers = "From:" . $from;

  mail($to,$subject, $message,$headers);

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'The mail sends successfully']);
  exit();
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.compform').on('submit', compformSubmit);

  function compformSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var target = $(event.target);
    var formData = {
      'name': target.find('input[name="name"]').val(),
      'mail': target.find('input[name="mail"]').val(),
      'submit': true
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url: 'compform.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data: formData, // our data object
        dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        // encode: true // this setting does not seem to exist
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        target.find('button').text('Success!');
      })
      .always(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        target.find('button').text('Always!');
      });
  }

});
```

**HTML**

```html
<form class="compform" action="compform.php" method="post">
  <input placeholder="Name" name="name">
  <input placeholder="Email" name="mail">
  <input placeholder="Type of Website" name="type">
  <select name="selectoptions">
    <option value="choose" disabled selected>Choose a Style</option>
    <option value="modern">Modern</option>
    <option value="serious">Serious</option>
    <option value="light">Light Tone</option>
    <option value="creative">Creative</option>
  </select>
  <textarea placeholder="Additional Information" name="info"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```